# NavigationView + TextField Background

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently learning SwiftUI and building a todo list app. On the ContentView screen I've got a NavigationView and a button that pops up an "add new task" textfield into the list. I suspect this is not the correct way to implement this but when the textfield shows up the background color doesn't persist. For the life of me I can't figure out how to set the background color. If I move the textfield outside the NavigationView I can set the background but when the NavigationView shifts to make space for the textfield I get a bunch of black screen flicker. Any thoughts on how I can set the background color on the textfield when added to the list or fix the screen flicker when I move it out? Appreciate the help.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(entity: ToDoItem.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)]) var listItems: FetchedResults<ToDoItem>

@State private var newToDoItem = ""
@State private var showNewTask = false
@State var isEditing = false
@State var showTaskView = false
@State var bottomState = CGSize.zero
@State var showFull = false
@State var deleteButton = false

//this removes the lines in the list view
init() {
    // To remove only extra separators below the list:
    UITableView.appearance().tableFooterView = UIView()

    // To remove all separators including the actual ones:
    UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none

    UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    //UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        VStack{
            TitleView()

            NavigationView {
                List {
                    if showNewTask {
                        HStack{
                            TextField("New task", text: self.$newToDoItem, onEditingChanged: { (changed) in
                            }) {
                                print("onCommit")
                                self.addTask(taskTitle: self.newToDoItem)
                                self.saveTasks()
                                self.showNewTask.toggle()
                                self.newToDoItem = ""
                            }
                            .font(Font.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("Text"))

                            Button(action: {
                                self.newToDoItem = ""
                                self.showNewTask.toggle()
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle").foregroundColor(Color("button"))
                                    .font(Font.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 6, bottom: 8, trailing: 6))
                        .background(Color("addNewTask"))
                        .cornerRadius(10.0)
                    }

                    ForEach(listItems, id: \.self) {item in
                        HStack {
                            Button(action: {
                                item.isComplete = true
                                self.saveTasks()
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5){
                                    self.deleteTaskTest(item: item)
                                }
                            }) {
                                if (item.isComplete) {
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                                        .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .bold))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1616941956, green: 0.9244045403, blue: 0.1405039469, alpha: 1)))
                                        .padding(.trailing, 4)
                                } else {
                                    Image(systemName: "circle")
                                        .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .bold))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("button"))
                                        .padding(.trailing, 4)
                                }
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                            ToDoItemView(title: item.title, createdAt: "\(item.createdAt)")
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    self.showTaskView.toggle()
                            }
                            .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.1) {
                                self.isEditing.toggle()
                                print("this is a long press test")
                            }
                        }
                        .listRowBackground(Color("background"))
                    }
                    .onMove(perform: moveItem)
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteTask)
                }
                .environment(\.editMode, .constant(self.isEditing ? EditMode.active : EditMode.inactive)).animation(Animation.spring())
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("ToDay"), displayMode: .large)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .background(Color("background"))
            }

            //ADD A NEW TASK BUTTON
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showNewTask.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
                        .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                        .background(Color("button"))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)

                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .blur(radius: showTaskView ? 20 : 0)
        .animation(.default)
        .padding(.top, 30)

        //BOTTOM CARD VIEW
        TaskView()
            .offset(x: 0, y: showTaskView ? 360 : 1000)
            .offset(y: bottomState.height)
            .animation(.timingCurve(0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 1, duration: 0.5))
            .gesture(
                DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                    self.bottomState = value.translation
                    if self.showFull {
                        self.bottomState.height += -300
                    }

                    if self.bottomState.height < -300 {
                        self.bottomState.height = -300
                    }

                } .onEnded { value in
                    if self.bottomState.height > 50 {
                        self.showTaskView = false
                    }
                    if (self.bottomState.height < -100 && !self.showFull) || (self.bottomState.height < -250 && self.showFull){
                        self.bottomState.height = -300
                        self.showFull = true
                    } else {
                        self.bottomState = .zero
                        self.showFull = false
                    }
                }
        )
    }
    .background(Color("background").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
}
```

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 11.4. I only replaced your custom colors with standard.

Comment: I'm also on 11.4. Just tried using standard colors and doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work. For whatever reason reworking the stacks fixed it.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(entity: ToDoItem.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)]) var listItems: FetchedResults<ToDoItem>

@State private var showCancelButton: Bool = false
@State private var newToDoItem = ""
@State private var showNewTask = false
@State var isEditing = false
@State var showTaskView = false
@State var bottomState = CGSize.zero
@State var showFull = false
@State var deleteButton = false

var itemName = ""

init() {
    // To remove all separators including the actual ones:
    UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none

    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    TitleView()
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                        .background(Color("background"))

                    // Enter new task view
                    if showNewTask {
                        HStack {
                            HStack {
                                TextField("New task", text: self.$newToDoItem, onEditingChanged: { (changed) in
                                }) {
                                    self.addTask(taskTitle: self.newToDoItem)
                                    self.saveTasks()
                                    self.showNewTask.toggle()
                                    self.newToDoItem = ""
                                }
                                .font(Font.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
                                .foregroundColor(Color("Text"))

                                Button(action: {
                                    self.newToDoItem = ""
                                    self.showNewTask.toggle()
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle").foregroundColor(Color("button"))
                                        .font(Font.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
                                }
                            }
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 6, bottom: 8, trailing: 6))
                            .background(Color("addNewTask"))
                            .cornerRadius(10.0)

                        }
                        .background(Color("background"))
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    }

                    List {
                        ForEach(listItems, id: \.self) {item in
                            HStack {
                                Button(action: {
                                    item.isComplete = true
                                    self.saveTasks()
                                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5){
                                        self.deleteTaskTest(item: item)
                                    }
                                }) {
                                    if (item.isComplete) {
                                        Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                                            .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .bold))
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1616941956, green: 0.9244045403, blue: 0.1405039469, alpha: 1)))
                                            .padding(.trailing, 4)
                                    } else {
                                        Image(systemName: "circle")
                                            .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .bold))
                                            .foregroundColor(Color("button"))
                                            .padding(.trailing, 4)
                                    }
                                }
                                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                                ToDoItemView(title: item.title, createdAt: "\(item.createdAt)")
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    //item.title = self.itemName
                                    self.showTaskView.toggle()
                                }
                                .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.1) {
                                    self.isEditing.toggle()
                                    print("this is a long press test")
                                }
                            }
                            .listRowBackground(Color("background"))
                        }
                        .onMove(perform: moveItem)
                        .onDelete(perform: deleteTask)
                    }
                    .environment(\.editMode, .constant(self.isEditing ? EditMode.active : EditMode.inactive)).animation(Animation.spring())
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("ToDay"), displayMode: .large)
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    .background(Color("background"))
                }
                .background(Color("background").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
            }

            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    //withAnimation(){
                    self.showNewTask.toggle()
                    //}
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
                        .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                        .background(Color("button"))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)

                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .blur(radius: showTaskView ? 20 : 0)

        //BOTTOM CARD VIEW
        TaskView()
            .offset(x: 0, y: showTaskView ? 360 : 1000)
            .offset(y: bottomState.height)
            .animation(.timingCurve(0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 1, duration: 0.5))
            .gesture(
                DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                    self.bottomState = value.translation
                    if self.showFull {
                        self.bottomState.height += -300
                    }

                    if self.bottomState.height < -300 {
                        self.bottomState.height = -300
                    }

                } .onEnded { value in
                    if self.bottomState.height > 50 {
                        self.showTaskView = false
                    }
                    if (self.bottomState.height < -100 && !self.showFull) || (self.bottomState.height < -250 && self.showFull){
                        self.bottomState.height = -300
                        self.showFull = true
                    } else {
                        self.bottomState = .zero
                        self.showFull = false
                    }
                }
        )
    }
    .animation(.default)
    .background(Color("background").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
}

func moveItem(indexSet: IndexSet, destination: Int){
    let source = indexSet.first!
    if source < destination {
        var startIndex = source + 1
        let endIndex = destination - 1
        var startOrder = listItems[source].order
        while startIndex <= endIndex {
            listItems[startIndex].order = startOrder
            startOrder = startOrder + 1
            startIndex = startIndex + 1
        }
        listItems[source].order = startOrder
    } else if destination < source {
        var startIndex = destination
        let endIndex = source - 1
        var startOrder = listItems[destination].order + 1
        let newOrder = listItems[destination].order
        while startIndex <= endIndex {
            listItems[startIndex].order = startOrder
            startOrder = startOrder + 1
            startIndex = startIndex + 1
        }
        listItems[source].order = newOrder
    }
    saveTasks()
    self.isEditing.toggle()
}

func deleteTask(indexSet: IndexSet){
    let source = indexSet.first!
    let listItem = listItems[source]
    //self.deleteButton.toggle()
    managedObjectContext.delete(listItem)
    saveTasks()
}

func deleteTaskTest(item: ToDoItem){
    managedObjectContext.delete(item)
    saveTasks()
}

func addTask(taskTitle: String) {
    let newTask = ToDoItem(context: managedObjectContext)
    newTask.title = taskTitle
    newTask.order = (listItems.last?.order ?? 0) + 1
    newTask.createdAt = Date()
}

func saveTasks() {
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```